# How to stop Go gorm from forcing a not null constraint on my self referencing foreign key in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I need to create a table that references itself in gorm, but cannot figure out why it is forcing a `not null` constraint on me. I am totally stumped. How can I get around this? I am using the AutoMigrate feature provided by gorm to create the table. The instant I remove the foreign key constraints the `not null` constraint goes away, but that's not what I want.

**Edited:** I am using the package "gorm.io/gorm" specifically, not the one on Github. This is also the only table giving me issues, any other tables which have foreign keys that reference other tables works as expected.

#### Go with foreign key

```
type User struct {
    ID *int `gorm:"primaryKey; type:serial"`
    Username string `gorm:"type: varchar(32) not null unique"`
    Password string `gorm:"type: varchar(128) not null"`
    ReferredBy *int
    Referrer *User `gorm:"foreignKey:ReferredBy;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,ONDELETE:SET NULL"`
}
```

#### Resulting SQL with foreign key according to pgAdmin

```
-- Table: public.users

-- DROP TABLE public.users;

CREATE TABLE public.users
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass),
    username character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    password character varying(128) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    referred_by integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('users_referred_by_seq'::regclass),
    CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT users_username_key UNIQUE (username),
    CONSTRAINT fk_users_referrer FOREIGN KEY (referred_by)
        REFERENCES public.users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE SET NULL
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.users
    OWNER to msmf;
```

#### Go without foreign key

```
// User Model. ReferredBy is self referencing Foreign Key
type User struct {
    ID *int `gorm:"primaryKey; type:serial"`
    Username string `gorm:"type: varchar(32) not null unique"`
    Password string `gorm:"type: varchar(128) not null"`
    ReferredBy *int
}
```

#### Resulting SQL without telling gorm there is a foreign key

```
-- Table: public.users

-- DROP TABLE public.users;

CREATE TABLE public.users
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass),
    username character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    password character varying(128) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    referred_by bigint,
    CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT users_username_key UNIQUE (username)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.users
    OWNER to msmf;
```

Comment: Does it only do this when self-referencing?

Comment: Yes, this is the only table I get issues with. Any other table using foreign keys works.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Seems like one to me too, but I wanted to check here first before putting up an issue on their GitHub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently `type:serial` tag does this. If you drop it the not null constraint won't be there either:

```golang
type User struct {
    ID       uint   `gorm:"primarykey"`
    Username string `gorm:"type: varchar(32) not null unique"`
    Password string `gorm:"type: varchar(128) not null"`
    ReferredBy *int
    Referrer   *User `gorm:"foreignKey:ReferredBy;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,ONDELETE:SET NULL;"`
}
```

[Reference github issue](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/3816).